# Result of perpendicularBisector method

Tags: java, geometry, jts

I'm new to JTS with Java.
I'd like to get perpendicular bisector of the line segment a-b.

- coordinate a(2,3)
- coordinate b(8,7)

I used perpendicularBisector method but I can't understand its result.
For me, seems like it is not related to perpendicular bisector at all.
Could you please explain result's meaning and how to use result for perpendicular bisector?

```java
package Sui;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Triangle;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.algorithm.HCoordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.algorithm.NotRepresentableException;

public class Suitwo {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println("");
        Suitwo main = new Suitwo();
        main.testCalcCoord();
    }

    public void testCalcCoord() {

        Coordinate[] coords = {new Coordinate(2, 3),
                               new Coordinate(8, 7),
                               new Coordinate(0, 0)};

        Triangle tri = new Triangle(coords[0],coords[1],coords[2]);
        HCoordinate hcoord = tri.perpendicularBisector(coords[0],coords[1]);

        Coordinate calccord = new Coordinate();
        double x = 0.0;
        double y = 0.0;
        try {
            calccord = hcoord.getCoordinate();
            x = hcoord.getX();
            y = hcoord.getY();
        } catch (NotRepresentableException e) {
            System.out.println("NotRepresentableException");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.print("calccord:");
        System.out.println(calccord);
        System.out.print("X:");
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.print("Y:");
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

#### RESULT

calccord:(-0.12, -0.08, NaN)

X:-0.12

Y:-0.08

Comment: I think I figured out what the result means, but it's in a form that is rather inconvenient if the goal is to obtain the actual line segment that represents the perpendicular bisector. If the primary goal is to explain the result, I'd hesitate (because I'm not sure whether I could explain it adequately). If the primary goal is to roughly explain the result, and show an alternative for the computation, I'd post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `hcoord` is what you are interested in. It is a structure of `x, y, w` and a point `p` is on the line if

```
hcoord.x * p.x + hcoord.y * p.y + hcoord.w = 0
```

The portion `(hcoord.x, hcoord.y)` describes the normal of the line. `hcoord.w` describes the distance of the line to the origin, scaled by the inverse length of the normal.

If you know one of the coordinates of a point on the line and you want to know the other, you can simply re-arrange the above formula to get:

```
p.x = (-hcoord.w - hcoord.y * p.y) / hcoord.x
p.y = (-hcoord.w - hcoord.x * p.x) / hcoord.y
```

Be aware of division by zero if the line is either horizontal or vertical.

If instead you want the bisector in parametric form (point `p` and direction `d`), you could use:

```
p1, p2 = the points of the line segments for which to calculate the bisector
p = 0.5 * (p1 + p2)
d = (p2.y - p1.y, p1.x - p2.x)
```

Comment: What is the `p` in the second code block supposed to be? Admittedly, (I should know this stuff, but) I didn't find a *really* reasonable way to obtain some reasonable (i.e. parametric) form of the bisector from the `hcoord`. The third code essentially computes the bisector, ignoring the `hcoord`, which is fairly trivial. I assumed that the main point of the question was a "deeper understanding" of what `hcoord` actually *is*, and how to use it sensibly...

Comment: I tried to explain that in the first part of the answer. `p` is any point on the line. `hcoord` is the homogeneous representation of the line. The definition of that is in the first code block.

Comment: OK, that was a misunderstanding - the point of the second block was to say that "If you have `p.x`, then you can compute `p.y`, and if you have `p.y`, then you can compute `p.x`" (that wasn't clear at first glance, because `p` appears on both sides of the equation). A side note: I find the homogenous form for `hcoord` particularly inconvenient. If you want to *use* it in any way, you have to compute `dx`, `dy`, and the center point of the line, and then essentially already *have*  what you need for the bisector. But well, that's how it is implemented ....

Comment: Well, it depends on how you want to use it. A line does not have a center. The homogeneous form is particularly useful if you want to determine on which side of the line a given point lies - just calculate the dot product with the point. It is positive if the point is on the one side and negative on the other. And it is zero if the point is on the line.

Comment: Thank you very much, "Marco13" and "Nico Schertler".